# trackbar value changed when move rihgt and left

Tags: c#

i want do code when Scroll track-bar right and do another code when Scroll left in Visual Studio 2013 ?
i try this code but not work

```
if(trackBar1.Value<trackBar1.Maximum)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Right");
}
if(trackBar1.Value>trackBar1.Maximum)
{
    MessageBox.Show("left");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i want do code when Scroll track-bar right and do another code when Scroll left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about use ValueChanged event? Hold value of TrackBar before change in some property and on ValueChanged event compare it.

```
private int valueBefore = 0;
private void TrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(TrackBar1.Value < valueBefore)
        MessageBox.Show("left");
    }else{
        MessageBox.Show("right");
    }
    valueBefore = TrackBar1.Value;
}
```

Comment: @Osama I gladly helped, please tag it as answered